# Removing \ from NSString (from escape sequences only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have tried (searching for) various possible solutions here on SO, in vain. Most of them simply replace all occurrences of backslashes, and don't respect backslashes that should otherwise be untouched.

For instance, if I have a **Hi, it\'s me. How\'re you doing?**, it should be **Hi, it's me. How're you doing?**. However, if someone tries to get creative with ASCII art, like

\\// \\// \\//

//\\ //\\ //\\

(WOW even SO won't let me add text as is, the above text needed extra backslashes to be displayed correctly.)

I cannot use `[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];` since it will replace ALL backslashes. I do not want that.

I would like the string to be displayed as is.

**NOTE:** The strings in question here are values in `NSDictionary`s received as JSON from a web service. The use is in a service like a chat client, so it is important that text is handled correctly.

**ULTRA IMPORTANT NOTE**: I'm open to all ideas like library functions, regular expressions, human sacrifices, as long it gets the job done.

Comment: What are the bets that you are seeing backslash characters in an NSLog statement that are not actually present in your data? I suggest you post an example and describe how you created it.

Comment: Keep in mind that if I code `@"Some string \n And another"`, there is no backslash character in the string (even though when you print the string the backslash may show up).  (And, yes, it gets real confusing.)

Comment: where are the `\'` combos are coming from? not from a regular keyboard, I assume.

Comment: He is processing JSON, so probably comes from a server. The problem is that (a) JSON contains backslashes that the JSON parser will correctly remove, and (b) an NSLog statement will display backslashes that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

try this ...i cannot understand your question but it may help full for you,i think so

```
- (void)remove:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString* const pattern = @"(\"[^\"]*\"|[^, ]+)";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];

    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:str
                                      options:0
                                        range:searchRange];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSLog(@"%@", [str substringWithRange:matchRange]);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

call this method..

```
NSString*  str = @"Hi, it\'s me. How\'re you doing?";
    [self remove:str];
```

then the output is

```
Hi, it's me. How're you doing?
```

Comment: This method does not replace anything.

Comment: Your regEx is failing. Only returns each word (in the for-each loop).

Comment: after for loop you add local string and assign your string value.

Comment: I will have to test all my cases, please give me a while.